# How can we pass data from one opened form to another?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can we pass data from one form to another opened form in winform?

In a windows application one form opens another form. When I am entering some data in parent form then that will reflect in another child form immediately.

How this will happen?

Answer (score 1):

Depends how fancy you want to get.

Simplest approach is just to call methods directly.

**Parent**

```
_child = new ChildForm();
```

then, when you detect updates (TextChanged, SelectedIndexChanged etc.)

```
_child.UpdateData(someDataCollectedFromParent)
```

**Child**

```
public void UpdateData(MyObject data)
{
    textBox1.Text = data.FirstName;
    textBox2.Text = data.SecondName;
}
```

Other than that, you could build your message passing mechanism or look into the [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33.aspx) infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged for MyObject.

```
public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     private object _data1;

     public object Data1
     {
       get{ return _data1;}
       set 
       { 
           _data1=value; 
           PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Data1"));
       }
     }
}
```

then in your child form, assign a function to receive this event on account of updating new data(s), as the following code demonstrates:

```
myObject1.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(m_PropertyChanged);
```

and m_PropertyChanged:

```
public void m_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
   // update your data here, you can cast sender to MyObject in order to access it
}
```

Regards,
S. Peyman Mortazavi

Comment: This would be something that I'd use to have a child send information to the parent, but not the other way around.  The child would need to have a reference to the parent to subscribe to its event in this example.