# getting values from previous forms in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, public

i have 2 forms that consist of around 20 TextBoxes and i want to save all 20 entries and show them all in the 3rd form, each being shown in different labels, i have saved all 20 data in individual `public static string`global variables, but having 20 `static` global variable takes a lot of memory and slows down the program, is there any other way to save these data and store them individually in labels ?

here is what i have tried:

first form:

```
public static string place_of_application;
public static string gender;

private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    place_of_application = PlaceOfApplication.Text;
    gender = identity.Text;
    ...
}
```

second form:

```
private void PrintTemplateForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label36.Text = userform2.place_of_birth;
    label34.Text = userform2.gender;
    ...    
}
```

thanks for the help

Comment: _"having 20 static global variable takes a lot of memory and slows down the program"_ there is no way 20 strings could have any measurable affect on your program's performance.

Comment: Sure, you could do for example in a `FormClosing` event handler.

Comment: Storing 20 global variables should not slow down your program but I agree it's inelegant. You can use a class instead with 20 properties. Or if the 20 text boxes are logically similar, use an array/list.

Comment: Consult [Pass Data From One Form to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204773/). Also, “having 20 static global variable” is highly unusual, you are probably doing something wrong. Post your code.

Comment: @stuartd well they are all static and that what i have heard about static variables, otherwise if that is a myth it will be much better for me to  keep it this way

Comment: @Sach unfortunately they vary a lot

Comment: You need to show your code. We're getting nowhere.

Comment: @Sach sorry for the confusion, i have updated my question, thank you

Comment: I recently calculated prime number up to 100 millions using the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). This requires to create an array of size 100 millions. The primes were found in less than one second! 20 strings are nothing in times of Gigabytes and Gigahertz.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have two forms, the main form and the secondary form. You have bunch of text boxes in main, and upon clicking a button you want to grab data from those and show them in form 2.

First I would define a class that represents data you want to send/receive. It seems to be some sort of personal data, so let's create a `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Obviously, you will have all your 20 things you want as properties in the class instead of just this two.

Now the idea is grab data from your text boxes and save in an instance of this object. Next, In the second form you want to launch, let's pass a `Person` object in the constructor. So the second form's code behind will look like this. We will save that `Person` information in form two, and then display on it's labels.

```
public partial class SecondForm : Form
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public SecondForm(Person person)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Person = person;
    }

    private void SecondForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblName.Text = Person.Name;
        lblAge.Text = Person.Age.ToString();
    }
}
```

Now in main form, when a button is clicked, we'll save the data to an instance of the `Person` class, then pass it into the constructor of `SecondForm` and then show it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var person = new Person();
        person.Name = txtName.Text;
        if (int.TryParse(txtAge.Text, out int age))
        {
            person.Age = age;
        }

        var form2 = new SecondForm(person);
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One approach could be to select all of your textboxes in your first form and in Properties windows of Visual Studio (i'm guessing you use this IDE) go to Modifiers property and select Public from the list,

[image]

Or you can directly edit Form1.Designer.cs file and change all of the textboxes you want from Private to Public, then you can access them directly from your 2nd form like this:

```cs
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.ShowDialog();
if (frm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    label1.Text = frm.textBox1.Text;
```

Comment: Just noting that this will only work if the form is still open..

Answer (score -1):

**I think you have [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).** You are asking for a very specific problem, when your issue is far more general with the architecture of the application.

---

**Recommendation**

Try to take advantage of the object oriented features of `C#` and build a data model (i.e. a class that contains all the data). Then you can pass around this class (or actually a reference to the class) from one form to the other. Each form will be responsible for populating their own text boxes from the data model, or generating a new instance of the data model from the text boxes.

As an added bonus, to this setup is that you can use data binding to automate the synchronization between your data model and the UI (i.e. the text boxes).

I strongly recommend reading a book on windows programming, or find online resources with examples. [SO] is not a good place to learn how to build windows applications properly.

---

**Example**

1. Data model is a class that holds data

   ```
   public class PersonalInformation
   {
       public string PlaceOfApplication { get; set; }
       public string Gender { get; set; }
       // .. more here
   }
   ```
2. Main form can receive or send data via a `PersonalInformation` object.

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       public PersonalInformation PersonalInformation
       {
           get
           {
               return new PersonalInformation()
               {
                   PlaceOfApplication = placeOfApplicationTextBox.Text,
                   Gender = genderTextBox.Text
               };
           }
           set
           {
               placeOfApplicationTextBox.Text = value.PlaceOfApplication;
               genderTextBox.Text = value.Gender;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. In the second form create a method to receive data

   ```
   public partial class Form2 : Form
   {
       public Form2()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       public void SetPersonalInformation(PersonalInformation value)
       {
           placeOfApplictionLabel.Text = value.PlaceOfApplication;
           genderLabel.Text = value.Gender;
       }
   }
   ```
4. In the first form handle the button press by preparing and sending the information to the second form

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       ...

       private void secondFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           var dlg = new Form2();
           dlg.SetPersonalInformation(this.PersonalInformation);

           if (dlg.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
           {
               // user pressed OK in second form
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. Test the process

[image: screenshot]